# How can I switch my Django project's database engine from Sqlite to MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, mysql-python

I need help switching my database engine from sqlite to mysql. manage.py datadump is returning the same error that pops up when I try to do anything else with manage.py : ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQL module, No module named MySQLdb.

This django project is a team project. I pulled new changes from bitbucket and our backend has a new configuration. This new configuration needs mysql (and not sqlite) to work. Our lead dev is sleeping right now. I need help so I can get started working again.

**Edit**: How will I get the data in the sqlite database file into the new MySQL Database?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [`Database setup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup) paragraph in Django docs:

> By default, the configuration uses SQLite.
>
> If you wish to use another database, install the appropriate [database
>   bindings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#database-installation)...

And [`Get your database running`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/#get-your-database-running) page says:

> If you’re using MySQL, you’ll need the MySQL-python package, version
>   1.2.1p2 or higher.

To use `MySQL` backend you need a tool that would help Django talk to the database, an adapter.

In other words, [`MySQL-python`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) (aka `MySQLdb`) package needs to be installed.

Answer (score -1):

Try the followings steps:
1. Change DATABASES in settings.py to MYSQL engine
2. Run $ ./manage.py syncdb